# How to avoid two sequential alerts (one for read and one for edit) when using `window.showDirectoryPicker()`

Tags: native-file-system-api-js, file-system-access-api

```js
const dirHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker();
await dirHandle.requestPermission({ mode: "readwrite" });
```

I'm using the File System Access API in chrome. I'd like to let the user pick a folder, then write into the folder.

My code works, but two alerts are shown sequentially, one for read and one for write:
[image]
[image]

The first one is unnecessary. How can I avoid it?

Interestingly, if the user uses drag and drop, only the 2nd alert will appear after the folder is dropped, which is the desired behavior. The first alert seems to come from `showDirectoryPicker`. In the ideal world, I imagine being able to pass in an option like `showDirectoryPicker({ permission: 'readwrite' })`, which will request the 2 permissions together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Chrome 105, you can get a writable directory with just one prompt

```
const dirHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker({ mode: "readwrite" });
```

Or be explicit in asking for a read-only directory (which is the default).

```
const dirHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker({ mode: "read" });
```

Answer (score -1):

I agree it feels suboptimal, but it's a one-time thing. When you run the same code again and pick the same folder (or a nested folder), there will be no prompts at all.

This design was chosen because there are two different things that are being asked here:

- First, for the app to *read* all files (which, recursively for subfolders can be a lot).
- Second, for the app to be allowed to *write* (anywhere) into the folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have two problems: 1. it's not a one-time thing because every time the user reloads the page and pick the same folder, the two alerts show again. 2. if the user provides the folder by drag and drop, the first alert won't show, but the "two different things" you mentioned are still both achieved

Comment: Yes, a reload will currently still show the prompts. There's thinking to weaken this, but nothing to announce quite yet.

Comment: does it allow to write into subfolders? If not, will that feature come?

Comment: If you have write access to a parent folder, then you also have write access to subfolders.